# How to include a blade template only if it exists?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

How to @include a blade template **only** if it exists ?
I could do something like that :

```
@if (File::exists('great/path/to/blade/template.blade.php'))
   @include('path.to.blade.template')
@endif
```

But that really isn't elegant and efficient.

I could include it without if statements, and catch & hide errors if the file isn't here, but that is a little dirty, if not barbaric.

What would be great is something like that :

```
@includeifexists('path.to.blade.template')
```

(pseudo code, but this blade command does not exist)

Comment: You could surely [extend Blade](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#extending-blade) by adding a custom function to hide the ```if``` statements, but I suppose it is only worthy if you have plenty of these cases to use it at.

Comment: I am just wondering why would you include something that does not exist or what would be the scenario you are trying to solve?

Comment: @mdamia : I have hundreds of page, with the same structure. Some have partials files. I include partial only for pages who need it. I could use two template : one who an inclusion directive for the pages who need it, and one without. But the logic is simpler in the first way.

Comment: Warning : Only use the described thing if you absolutely need it. Two cons about it : first, as it is not a standard approach, your colleagues will get confused in the first place - this doesn't comply with KISS principles. Second, I guess it will result in slightly slower pages, as PHP will have to check if a file exist to include it (I guess).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `View::exists()` to check if a view exists or not.

```
@if(View::exists('path.to.view'))
    @include('path.to.view')
@endif
```

Or you can extend blade and add new directive

```
Blade::directive('includeIfExists', function($view) {

});
```

Check out the official document here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#extending-blade

Comment: This is correct. In your first example, you missed a  ' at the end of the include parameter.

Answer (score 40):

Had a similar issue. Turns out there is an `@includeIf` blade directive for this purpose.

Simply do `@includeIf('path.to.blade.template')`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

When needed in a Controller ([from this documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views)):

Determining If A View Exists If you need to determine if a view
 exists, you may use the exists method after calling the  view helper
 with no arguments. This method will return true if the view exists on
 disk:

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;`

```
if (View::exists('emails.customer')) {
    \\
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Late to the show, but there's another quite handy template function:

Often you'd like to include a template when it is present, *or* include some other template if not. This could result in quite ugly if-then constructs, even when you use '@includeIf'. You can alse do this:

`@includeFirst([$variableTemplateName, "default"]);`

This will include - as the function name suggests - the first template found.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel >= 7, there directive `includeIf`

```
@includeIf('view.name', ['some' => 'data'])
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#including-subviews